# Interpreting docs.python.org syntax

Tags: python, return

I wanted to learn how to properly use [return](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) from  the docs.python.org. But I was hindered by my ignorance on how to read their expression syntax. For example, [expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists), how does one interpret:

```
return_stmt ::=  "return" [expression_list]
expression_list    ::=  expression ("," expression)* [","]
```

Comment: Brackets means "optional".  Splat `"*"` means "repeated 0 or more times".  All that says is that `return` can either stand alone, or it can be followed by any Python expression or tuple of expressions.

Comment: That's actually an older version of the grammar. A return statement is currently defined as `return_stmt: 'return' [star_expressions]` (at least in the full grammar page). The older `expression_list` came, IIUC, from the old LL(1) grammar, but Python now uses a PEG grammar.

Comment: Looks like the documentation is using [Extended Backus-Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). ETA: This is partly confirmed by the Python docs, which say, "The notation is a mixture of EBNF and PEG." (See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)

Comment: [PEP 617](https://peps.python.org/pep-0617/) discusses the new grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `return` statement can be left on its own (square brackets indicate optional values).

```
def foo():
  return
```

Or have one required *expression*, to many (`*` means zero-to-many), separated by comma

```
def bar()
  return True, (x for x in range(5) if x > 2), [1, 2, 3]
```

Or if there is a comma after the required expression (or the list of expressions), it returns a tuple

```
>>> def baz():
...   return True,
...
>>> baz()
(True,)
```